# Is it possible to embed TTS in Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Unhapilly my language doesn't have support for TTS in stock Android. So, my users have to download a third party TTS voice engine.
This is QUITE annoying since it requires extra steps to get my software working.

**Is there ANY way to EMBED any third party TTS engine (with its corresponding language pack) in an Android app?**

Any help is appreciatted!

Answer (score 0):

**No**,It is not possible.

You have to **download third party TTS** from android market then install it Or you can **keep third party TTS .apk** into assets and then install it.

After that you need to **download corresponding voice data** from server whose size is ranging from 32Mb to 160MB.

Then you need to **set this tts as default tts engine** in android **Voice input and output**. setting(Externally).

Then you need to set your language if user have chosen **Always use my settings** in android setting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can embed a third party TTS in android. But I have done it using java. 
there is an open source library available as freetts.jar.
Just go through this video tutorial and you will get the procedure. You can try implementing the same in android.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKAXzpnWXNU

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The link is rotten.