# How to choose male voice in Google text to Speech API

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I want male voice output from google text to speech API, is there any parameter to send for male voice, Now i'm getting female voice(default). i'm Using below URL.
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&textlen=32&client=tw-ob&q=Hello+world&tl=en 
Please help me to solve this.

Thanks & Regards

Thiru.

Comment: guess it's not possible in a conventional way

Comment: Please try to read and do with this, [One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164060/android-texttospeech-change-gender-voices) [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815245/android-text-to-speech-male-voice) [Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115458/is-it-possible-to-embed-tts-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

According to the official REST API [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate),

There is no way to configure the voice. Neither pitch, speed nor gender. However you can get the translated text and output it using Google’s Text-to-speech. For this you need to manually download the male voice file. See [Google Text-to-speech adds multiple male and female voices](http://www.androidauthority.com/google-text-to-speech-multiple-male-female-voices-673214/)

Comment: Hi Thank you for your information.. but i cant able to use downloaded male voice which is in apk file. i'm using "wget -q -U Mozilla -O output.wav URL" this way to get output voice and processing with that output file.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set pitch of voice you can not set male voice...

```
 TTS.setPitch();
```

value u can set but it is very bad u should try another texttospeech engine or stay with default female voice.

Comment: Do you know any better TTS Engine other than Google?

Comment: You can try the TTS library (https://pypi.org/project/TTS/)